# Erasing a bunch of contacts at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

My friend got an iPhone from her uncle and started using it without wiping out all the data. Now she wants to delete all the existing contacts on the phone (over 500) but doesn't want to reset the entire phone. Is there any easy way to delete multiple contacts at once?

Right now she has to go into each one, press edit, and then press delete. The contacts are not synced to any service, they are only located on the phone itself.

Comment: Does she sync the device to a computer?

Comment: @KyleCronin: nope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Cleanup: remove all contacts](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cleanup-remove-multiple-contacts/id376235560?mt=8) app from the appstore to do this. The app costs $0.99

[image]

If you want a Mac only solution, you can backup the contacts in your mac's Address Book, connect your phone to your mac and set it to sync only your address book in iTunes. Once it's done syncing (it should now be a clean slate), you can change the sync settings to whatever you wish and then restore your existing contacts from the backup.